# How do I get undeclared php variable highlighting in idea?

Tags: php, variables, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

Given a php class like:

```
<?php

/**
 * A class description.
 *
 * @property int id
 * @property string name
 *
 */

class myClass {

  public function hasId() {
    if ($this->id) { 
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

}
?>
```

I would like to have highlighting that $this->id is never declared. I know in PHP that isn't strictly required but our in house standards are asking for it. Is there a way to get this in Intellij/Idea?

Comment: You mean you want IntelliJ to warn you that `$this->id` is never declared in the code? Maybe it doesn't warn you now because you've told it in the comments.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. And that is what I was afraid of (and why I made sure to include them.) I don't understand though why it would consider comments to be declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove your doc  `@property int id`. You'll get the warning once you remove it. IntelliJ uses those docs as additional information about a class. You're basically telling IntellJ that the class does have those properties.

There is no way to tell IntelliJ to ignore those comments.

Comment: Thanks. I guess that means it's over to Zend Studio for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Main class 
class Main{

//Let main class has variable $id
public $id = '123';

}

class myClass extends Main{

  public function hasId() {
    //Check it!
    if (isset($this->id)) { 
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

}

$newclass = new myClass;

var_dump($newclass->hasId());
```

Result:

```
bool(true)
```

If we comment line with variable declaration //public $id = '123';

Result:

```
bool(false)
```

Comment: He wants his IDE to warn him about `$this->id` being undeclared, not a way to check wether it is or not in running code...